# function that randomly sorts through letters and changes them not working

Tags: javascript

I am making a javascript function that will input a string, and output a "spongebob mocking text"
basically, you input "Hello, this is a message to the world" and you would get "HeLlO, ThIS iS a MeSsAGe tO tHE wORlD"
basically, randomly decide wheather to capitalize a letter or not. I made a function which i thought would do that, but it didn't work. here is the code that I tested in the js console:

```
function memify(input) { // function called memify()

var il = input.length;  // gets the length of the input
var newinput = input; // creates a new variable that will be changed from input.

  for (var i=0;i>il;i++) {

  var rng = Math.floor((Math.random()*2)); // random number between 0 and 1. 0 = upper 1 = lower

  if (rng === 0) {


    newinput.charAt(i).toUpperCase();


  }
  else {

    newinput.charAt(i).toLowerCase();

  }



  }


 return newinput; 
}
var text = prompt();
var textmeme = memify(text);
alert(textmeme);
```

Why is this not working? Do I have an error in my code? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: strings are immutable. `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` don't mutate the original string.

Comment: @ASDFGerte oh, so should I make a new variable and update that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

`newinput.charAt(i).toUpperCase();`

you're creating a new uppercase character, but you aren't doing anything with it; it's just an unused expression, so there's no visible change. Primitives (including strings) are immutable - you should explicitly reassign a string to something else (eg `newString += newinput.charAt(i).toUpperCase();`) to see an effect.

You also need to use

```
for (var i = 0; i < il; i++) {
//                ^
```

instead of

```
for (var i = 0; i > il; i++) {
//                ^
```

else, no iterations will run at all.

```js
function memify(input) { // function called memify()
  var il = input.length; // gets the length of the input
  let changedStr = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < il; i++) {
    var rng = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2)); // random number between 0 and 1. 0 = upper 1 = lower
    if (rng === 0) {
      changedStr += input.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
    } else {
      changedStr += input.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  return changedStr;
}
var text = prompt();
var textmeme = memify(text);
console.log(textmeme);
```

Another option, using `.map`, which looks much cleaner IMO:

```js
const memify = input => [...input]
  .map(char => Math.random() < 0.5 ? char.toUpperCase() : char.toLowerCase())
  .join('');

console.log(memify(prompt()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Or more concise, safer and generally better solution :). It does not require for loop, checking length of string and other error prone stuff.

```js
function memify(input) {
    var rng = () => Math.random() > 0.5; 
    var res = input.split('').map( letter => 
        rng() ? letter.toUpperCase() : letter.toLowerCase()
    ).join('');
    return res;
}

var textmeme = memify("Hello World");
console.log(textmeme);
```

Please up-vote if it was helpful :)